# Cocoa - PDFView/ThumbnailView dragging

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a PDFView and a PDFThumbnailView and implemented it this way:

```
class PDFViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfThumbnailView: PDFThumbnailView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.

        let doc = PDFDocument(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: "file.pdf")!)
        pdfView.setDocument(doc)
        pdfView.setAllowsDragging(true)
        pdfThumbnailView.setPDFView(pdfView)
        pdfThumbnailView.setAllowsDragging(true)
    }
}
```

Since the documentation says:

> Sets whether users can drag thumbnails within the thumbnail view; that
>   is, re-order pages in the document.

I thought this would do it, but it isn't doing anything. I can't drag and drop and so reorder the document.

Comment: Are you testing this in MacOS 10.12? If so, don't bother, Apple really messed up PDFView/PDFThumbnailView in 10.12. PDFThumbnailView isn't responsive at all, you can't even click on a page to select it. In some cases, it doesn't even render the thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

Connect pdfThumbnailView and pdfView before setting the document, in the xib or in code.